# keepalived doesn't detect loss of virtual IP

Tags: keepalived

I'm using keepalived to switch a floating IP between two VMs.

`/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf` on VM 1:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface ens160
    virtual_router_id 101
    priority 150
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass secret
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        1.2.3.4
    }
}
```

`/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf` on VM 2:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface ens160
    virtual_router_id 101
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass secret
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        1.2.3.4
    }
}
```

This basically works fine, with one exception: Everytime systemd gets updated (it's running Ubuntu 18.04) it reloads it's network component, resulting in dropping the floating IP because it's not configured in the system. Since both keepalived instances still can ping each other, none of them sees anything wrong and none of them reacts on this, resulting in the floating IP staying down.

I found that you can check for the IP with a simple script like this:

```
vrrp_script chk_proxyip {
    script "/sbin/ip addr |/bin/grep 1.2.3.4"
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    # [...]
    track_script {
        chk_proxyip
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is a working approach.

If I understand it correctly the following would happen, if I configure this script on VM1:

1. VM1 loses the IP due to a systemd restart
2. keepalived on VM1 detects the loss of the IP
3. keepalived switches to `FAULT` state and stops broadcasting vrrp packages
4. keepalived on VM2 detects the loss of keepalived on VM1 and puts the floating IP up

At this point the IP is working again on VM2, but VM1 would stay in this state because the IP never comes up again on VM1. If VM2 goes down (for whatever reason) VM1 wouldn't take it over, because it is still in `FAULT` state.

How can I ensure that the floating IP is always up on one of the VMs?

Further tests:

I tried to ping the floating IP instead of checking if it is active on a specific host in a check_script:

```
vrrp_script chk_proxyip {
    script "/bin/ping -c 1 -w 1 1.2.3.4"
    interval 2
}
```

Configuring this script on node 2 resulted in the following:

1. removed the IP on node 1 for testing
2. node 2 detected the IP loss and changed from `BACKUP` to `FAULT`
3. node 1 ignored the state change and stayed `MASTER`

The result: the IP stayed down.

Configuring the script on node 1 resulted in the following:

1. removed the IP on node 1
2. node 1 detected the IP loss and changed from `MASTER` to `FAULT`
3. node 2 detected the state change on node 1 and changed from `BACKUP` to `MASTER`, configuring the floating IP on node 2

Well, and then ...

```
Feb 13 10:11:26 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:27 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:29 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received advert with higher priority 150, ours 100
Feb 13 10:11:29 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Feb 13 10:11:32 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:33 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:36 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received advert with higher priority 150, ours 100
Feb 13 10:11:36 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Feb 13 10:11:38 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:39 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:41 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received advert with higher priority 150, ours 100
Feb 13 10:11:41 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Feb 13 10:11:44 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:45 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Feb 13 10:11:47 node2 Keepalived_vrrp[3486]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received advert with higher priority 150, ours 100
...
```

I had to restart keepalived on node1 to stop the ping pong game between the nodes.

Comment: why don't use a true cluster soluction as pacemaker?

Comment: I haven't used pacemaker before, that's why I went with keepalived. But everything I read about *pacemaker vs keepalived* suggests that for this use case keepalived is the better choice.

Comment: Can I ask what service the vip offer ? as if it's like nginx there is some script to use with nginx+keepalaive like you do, like shown there; https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/aws-high-availability-keepalived/?_ga=2.85283985.965715184.1550673538-1625386790.1550673538  I guess the goal is to change the service binding to the correct IP if the VM get the VIP.

Comment: It's haproxy which balances between multiple LDAP servers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We experienced this issue and decided it is an issue with systemd-networkd in ubuntu 18.04 now using netplan.  A newer version of keepalived should fix this as it can detect the removal of the floating IP which causes a failover, see https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/issues/836.

The newer version of keepalived is not available in 18.04, and rather than trying to backport we decided to stay on ubuntu 16.04 and wait until ubuntu 20.04 for our servers that use keepalived.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is fixed in keepalived 2.0.0 from 2018-05-26, see [changelog of keepalived](https://www.keepalived.org/changelog.html)

> - Monitor VIP/eVIP deletion and transition to backup if a VIP/eVIP
>     is removed unloes it is configured with the no-track option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make a ping check on the floating ip then when it fails restart the keepalived service on all nodes

Youre ip wil com back

Put this in a cronjob which runs every minute or 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I think your general approach is fine, but that you need rethink your test condition. The condition that you are concerned about, is whether systemd is restarting the network infra (the indirect consequence of that being, whether or not your VIP is up), so that is what you need to check for.

I don't have a system that I can easily test on as I type this, so YMMV, however `systemctl is-active network.service` may be sufficient to cover this. Failing that checking the state of `systemctl show network.service | grep 'ActiveState'` for a state other than 'active' should do it.

As an aside, should one of your nodes not be configured with the state 'BACKUP', rather than both as 'MASTER'?

Comment: `systemctl is-active network.service` always shows `inactive`, so that doesn't really work. But even if it would be `active`, I don't really think the fact that an additional IP that is not configured permanently in the system exists or not exists would make any difference on the service. Thanks anyway for the input.

Comment: Oh, and the configured `state` is only the startup state. The node with the lower priority drops to `BACKUP` as soon as it gets the first VRRP packages from the node with the higher priority. I found this as a recommended configuration when I configured the nodes.

Comment: You said: "Everytime systemd gets updated (it's running Ubuntu 18.04) it reloads it's network component" so that is the condition you need to test for, not whether the VIP that is dependent on that condition is present. As I mentioned, I wasn't able to test as I didn't have a machine that I could disturb the network, so take your point that you will need to find an alternative test, but that fundamentally is what you need to do.

Comment: Ok, I just tried reinstalling systemd while constantly running `systemctl is-active network.service`. You are right, this command reports a different result during the update process, but only very briefly. Running this command every 2 seconds (or even 1 second) by keepalived and hoping it runs in the few milliseconds it takes systemd to reconfigure the network is not a check I want to trust for one of my main infrastructure services.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider keepalived doesn't manage split brain :)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider have you tried monitoring age of files in /var/run/systemd/netif/ for detecting systemd-networkd restarting?  I see they change when systemd-networkd is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I configured the floating IP as an additional IP on the primary node (with the higher priority)

*/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml*:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [ 1.2.3.5/24, 1.2.3.4/24 ]
      gateway4: 1.2.3.254
      nameservers:
          search: [ example.com ]
          addresses:
              - "1.2.3.40"
```

This way, upon boot or systemd reconfigure the floating IP is on the primary node. Should it fail, it is taken over by the secondary node via keepalived. Should the primary node return the IP is released by keepalived on the secondary node.

It's not really a solution, but currently I don't see anything better.

---

**Update**

While this workaround kinda worked, it had some side effects. After a reboot the floating IP address existed twice on the interface:

```
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:a3:d7:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.5/24 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 1.2.3.4/32 scope global ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 1.2.3.4/24 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global secondary ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This didn't seem to affect anything, it worked, but it bothered me. In the end I resulted in [the answer by mp3foley](https://serverfault.com/a/956219/38644) and reinstalled the VMs with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: the double ips could be fixed if you give the netowork to the virtual_adress as in `1.2.3.4/24` instead of 1.2.3.4